# How to maximise your profit as a salesman? Python dynamic programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

> Given two list of lists, you have to find the best cities to travel to to maximise your earnings.
>
> Assume you start at day 0
>
> The first list `money_day = [[ 1,   1], [ 99, 2]]` represents the amount of money you will make on a specific day at a particular city. money[i][j] represents the amount of money made on day i at city j. e.g. money_day[0][0] will be the amount of money you make on day 0 at city 0 which is £1.
>
> The second list `possible_travel= [[0, 1], [None, 0]]` represents the amount of days you need to travel to from city to city. possible_travel[i][j] will be how long it will take to go from city i to city j. e.g. possible_travel[0][1] means it will take 1 day to travel from city 0 to city 1. None means that there is no road from city i to city j
>
> - Selling at a certain city will take one whole day (if you sell on day 2 you cannot travel or sell again until day 3
> - You can visit the same city to sell again
> - Travelling will also take x days (if you start travel on day 2 for 2 days you cannot do anything until day 4)

Currently I have the following code that doesn't seem to work for larger lists.

```
def most_money(start, money_day, possible_travel):
    tab = [-10] * len(money_day)
    for days in possible_travel[start]:
        tracker = 0
        if possible_travel[start][days] is None:
            continue 
        else:
            tab[possible_travel[start][days]] = max(money_day[days][possible_travel[start][days]] + tracker, tab[possible_travel[start][days]])
            tracker += tab[possible_travel[start][days]]
    return memo
```

I'm having trouble breaking the problem up into sub-problems then combining, I'm also not sure if recursion is a better approach.

Comment: There are a couple of syntax errors, but the overall algorithm i'm going for is there

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down like this: On each day, you either stay in the same city, which means you make that day's profits there and start again in the same city on the next day, or you travel to another city, which means you start over in that city after the travel time.

In code, treating `money_day` and `possible_travel` as global constants for simplicity, and assuming that no travel time to another city is 0:

```py
last_day = len(money_day) - 1
cities = set(range(len(possible_travel)))

def most_money(day, city):
    """Return how much money is left to be made, 
    if the current state is given by day, city."""
    if day > last_day:
        return 0
    if day == last_day:
        return money_day[day][city]  
    return max([money_day[day][city] + most_money(day + 1, city)] +
               [most_money(day + possible_travel[city][next_city], next_city) 
                for next_city in cities - {city}
                if possible_travel[city][next_city] is not None])
```